# DRF: static/read-only/non-model fields in serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to include static fields in a model serializer? For example, I have a model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    long = models.FloatField(...)
    lat = models.FloatField(...)
```

and a serializer:

```
class LocationSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ("id", "long", "lat")
```

with a simple `ListAPIView` I can see all my locations:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'long': ...,
    'lat': ...,
}, 
...
```

but say I want to have a static, non-model field added to all objects in my json response? Something like:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'long': ...,
    'lat': ...,
    'display': True,
    'icon': 'image/marker.png'
}, 
...
```

How can I add these to the serializer? I've looked through the [`fields`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/2.4.4/rest_framework/fields.py) module (for 2.2.4) but I don't see any clear way of achieving this. Everything needs a `source` attribute.

Ideally I would like to do

```
class LocationSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    display = fields.BooleanField(value=True)
    icon = fields.CharField(value="image/marker.png")

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ("id", "long", "lat")
```

---

**EDIT**

One approach I've found is to simply put extra `@property` wrapped methods on the model instance:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    long = models.FloatField(...)
    lat = models.FloatField(...)

    @property
    def show(self):
        return True

    ...
```

and then in the serializer:

```
class LocationSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    display = fields.BooleanField(value=True)
    icon = fields.CharField(value="image/marker.png")

    show = fields.CharField(source="show")

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ("id", "long", "lat")
```

but this seems very hacky. There must be a cleaner way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this field is a property or method on your model (like `get_full_name`, for instance), you can have a custom `source` on serializer fields that points to them. Django REST Framework will automatically detect that they are methods, and will still call and display them.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    # ...

    def display(self):
        return True

    def icon(self):
        return "image/marker.png"

class LocationSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    display = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    icon = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ("id", "long", "lat", "display", "icon", )
```

If you can't or don't want to put the function on your model, Django REST Framework has [a `SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield) that will call a method on your serializer that can return data that will be displayed.

```
class LocationSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    display = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_display")
    icon = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_icon")

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ("id", "long", "lat", "display", "icon", )

    def get_display(self, obj):
        return True

    def get_icon(self, obj):
        return "image/marker.png"
```

Comment: Ah, I had figured out the first approach but the second one makes much more sense. I missed it [in the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#serializermethodfield).